# Python: Formating JSON file when writing embedded lists

Tags: python, json

I want to write JSON file using an appended list, but want that list to be of a certain format so it's easily readable in a text editor.

Given the following:

```
from json import load,dump
fid = open("tempfile.json", "w")
TC1 = 0
TC2 = 0
TC3 = 0
bigvalues = []

for x in range(0,3)
     TC1 += 1
     TC2 += 2
     TC3 += 3
     values = [TC1, TC2, TC3]
     bigvalues.append(values)

dump({"List Contents":bigvalues}, fid, indent=4)
fid.close()
```

I want the contents of the file in a text editor to look something like

{
     "List Contents":  [

```
  [1, 2, 3],

  [2, 4, 6],

  [3, 6, 9],
  ]
```

}

Instead, the list contents look similar

[1,

2,

3],

[2,

4,

6],

[3,

6,

9]

I don't care so much about indentations as much as I want each list to be on a single row, and the start of the list to align.  How do I achieve this with json file writes?

Comment: You probably would have to write a JSON serializer for this.

Comment: The problem is that it needs to be something that json can load again - and your style isn't valid json. If you write your own serializer, it would be a json-ish data structure usable by your program only, but not json.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the **pprint** library. The pprint library is a nice formatting tool for outputs of lists and such. I included the code that will give you the output you are looking for:

```
from json import load,dump
import pprint
fid = open("tempfile.json", "w")
TC1 = 0
TC2 = 0
TC3 = 0
bigvalues = []

for x in range(0,3):
     TC1 += 1
     TC2 += 2
     TC3 += 3
     values = [TC1, TC2, TC3]
     bigvalues.append(values)

dump({"List Contents":bigvalues}, fid, indent=4)

for item in bigvalues:
    pprint.pprint(item)
fid.close()
```

That will output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 4, 6]
[3, 6, 9]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `pprint` is for formatting Python data structures, not JSON.

Comment: That's fine for printing to screen, but I want the actual file contents to be as described